# Laravel - Limit eloquent query requests (throttle?)

Tags: php, laravel, limit, throttling

I'm currently developing a **coupon / discount** feature in Laravel with LiveWire

I have a perfectly working function that checks **if the coupon code is valid.**

```
public function refreshCart(Request $request = NULL)
{

    $this->cart = Session::has('cart') ? Session::get('cart') : null;

    // Reset previously entered coupon
    $this->coupon = NULL;

    // Check if new coupon code is valid
    if ($this->couponCode){
      $coupon = Coupon::where('code', "=", $this->couponCode)->first();
      if ($coupon !== NULL){
        $this->coupon = $coupon;
      }
    }
}
```

The problem is, this is not very safe.
I'd like to limit the requests for `Coupon::where(...)`

So that

- This function can not get called like 10 times a second globally
- One user (based on session) can only try like 10 times a minute

Is there a way to achieve this with default Laravel functions, or should I create a database scheme for this?
How could I achieve that? I've found nothing related on stackoverflow.

Thanks!